# AngularJS - where should this go? Controller or Link?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a need to call $compile in my directive. Most examples that talk about DOM manipulation say this should be done in the link function.

But if I'm watching a model property then surely I can use ng-change and handle this in the controller? Both work anyway.

Directive HTML template:

`<div>
    <div>
        <select ng-model="myProperty" ng-change="onChange()">
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="toBeReplaced"></div>
</div>`

JS directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('myDirective', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    var markup = '<div>{{ property }}</div>';

    return {
        templateUrl: '/views/template.html',
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
            // other controller code that I need.


            $scope.onChange = function(){
                $element.find("#toBeReplaced").html(markup);

                $compile($element.contents())($scope);
            };
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('myProperty', function(newVal, oldVal){
                if(oldVal !== newVal) {
                    element.find("#toBeReplaced").html(markup);

                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Is there any reason not to use the controller solution?

Comment: As per angular documentation, use controller only if you want to communicate with this directive from another directive

Comment: And couldn't you avoid this whole 'jQuery-like' html binding with just [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)? Also, your `$element.find` will not work with jqlite as jqlite only [finds by tag name](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

Comment: @Ahmad I have read that but it seems limited. If a directive has it's own scope, should I use a controller for it to set up it's model properties and methods?

Comment: @DominikSchreiber THanks. I just knocked this up very quickly. Getting the elements is neither here nor there for my question :). Could you point me to somewhere useful for ng-bind-html? I was wondering how I could incorporate it.

Comment: @DominikSchreiber if JQuery is loaded before Angular, then it will replace JQLite and `element.find` will work with IDs.

Comment: @AlexB here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/jZS8C/. Other than this, the [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) api documentation has some info that might help you.

Comment: Thanks @DominikSchreiber. Is there any way to dynamically create the HTML tag parts? Like <{{ tag }}>My HTML</{{ tag }}>. I imagine it breaks because it doesn't interpolate before it renders.

Comment: But you could call `$interpolate` just yourself like `$scope.markup = $interpolate('<my-html-directive>blah</my-html-directive>')($scope)`.

Comment: @AlexB, no, there is no need, the scope variable represents your model in the view